# What could be causing Azure In-Role Caching process linear memory growth?

Tags: asp.net, caching, azure, azure-caching

We've noticed that on our web roles that the Azure "CacheService" Windows process' memory usage grows linearly. What could be causing this?

A memory leak right? Well no, because we aren't even using it. Azure in-role caching was only left on as on oversight from a previous feature that got removed. We've now turned it off, and did this without having to make any changes to our application, which should prove that we weren't actually using it and therefore the memory leak scenario is not possible.

As expected, the Windows process doesn't even run now that in-role caching has been turned off, and we no longer have a problem. However, we'd still like to know what was happening in-case we need to use it again. Here are some more details:

- The growth was almost exactly linear, in the short and long term.
- The rate of growth was about 200mb/day
- After a deployment it started at about 600mb memory usage.
- Memory usage would climb to about 4.2GB, over 50% of total RAM, even though cache size was set to a max of 30%. At this point it caused issues.
- Site usage is not linear. There are times when there are no users, and others when there are hundreds of simultaneous users.

Perhaps having in-role caching turned on allows the web app to use it for built-in caching of some sort. For example, MVC bundles are cached in the HttpRuntime.Cache, so may be something similar is happening? I'm not aware of any such mechanism, and even if there was why would memory usage grow in such a linear fashion and just keep growing?

We could turn it back on and write a web page/handler to list all the items in the Azure cache and see if that sheds any light on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue and found this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2014/01/10/in-role-cache-demystified.aspx

which explains as follows:

> Sometimes the cache service can show memory usage more than it is
>   configured for and the reason again can be expired, evicted objects,
>   excessive usage of regions, tags and notifications. You will the
>   working set for cache service increasing. Don’t be alarmed if you see
>   this because this may be a situation where GC hasn’t yet kicked in to
>   free up memory. Typically after the Gen 2 collection from GC the
>   memory usage should drop to normal.

You could also turn on RDP into one of the instances and check the performance counters assuming you have enabled diagnostic monitoring correctly. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh914135.aspx#AzureSDK24